# Why accessing indices greater than vector of bool size behaves differently than vector of int?

Tags: c++, stdvector

Consider the following code

```
string s;
cin >> s;
vector<bool> deleted(int(s.size()));
int t;
cin >> t;
while (t--) {
    char x;
    cin >> x;
    deleted[x - 'a'] = true;
}
for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
    if (deleted[s[i] - 'a']) continue;
    cout << s[i];
}
cout << "\n";
```

The above code takes a string consisting of lowercase English letters and `t` lowercase English letters to remove from `s`.

Input like the following should cause accessing out of bounds, but it seems like it's valid, since it prints the correct result "hod"

```
howdy
2
w
y
```

`w` and `y` will access indices `22` and `24` which is obviously greater than vector size.

Comment: "should cause accessing out of bounds" what did you expect to happen? Undefined behavior is undefined

Comment: The `[]` indexing operator have no bounds-checking. If you want bounds checking then you should use the `at` function (which incur a performance penalty because of the bounds checking).

Comment: note that there is a flaw in your logic. suppose you are asked to calculate 3+3, you take a die and roll a 6, is this sufficient to conclude that rolling dice is a good way to add numbers?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I changed the type to int, it behaves differently it prints incorrect results, seems like something special about the vector of bool.

Comment: Wow, that behavior sounds really undefined.

Comment: it is out of bounds in both cases. C++ is not a nanny language. It does not even attempt to produce compiler errors or expressive runtime error for all things that can you can do wrong. Use `at` if you want bounds checking

Comment: @MohamedMagdy *Input like the following should cause accessing out of bounds* -- That's what happened -- so what is the issue?

Comment: Note that `x - 'a'` will fail for anything not a lower-case letter, or if the encoding is different from ASCII (that pattern is only portable and standardized for digits).

Comment: @MohamedMagdy Indeed `std::vector<bool>` is special (but not in a good way, imo). An out-of-bounds-access will still cause undefined behaviour, regardless of the type of vector. Undefined behaviour means, anything can happen.

Comment: These duplicates doesn't answer my question.

Comment: There's no need to save information about the characters to delete. After `std::can >> x;` just remove all occurrences of `x` from the string.

Comment: @MohamedMagdy *but it seems like it's valid, since it prints the correct result "hod"* -- You buy 10 ropes that are rated to hold only 500 pounds.  You then tie 600 pounds to each of those ropes -- 6 break immediately, 4 don't break.   You get 10 more ropes, you run the same test -- now 9 ropes break and 1 doesn't break.  That's what you're doing here -- you broke the rules of accessing an out-of-bounds item -- there is no guarantee what will happen when you do that.

Comment: Re: "letters to remove from `s`" -- but the code doesn't remove anything from `s`. It displays characters from `s` that are not in the deleted list, but it leaves `s` unchanged.

Comment: @PeteBecker But that's O(n) where `n` is the size of the string. I'm asked to print the nonremoved characters.

Comment: The loop `for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)` already makes the algorithm O(n). That you don't print all the characters in the string is irrelevant for the complexity.

Comment: @MohamedMagdy *These duplicates doesn't answer my question.* -- I'll be honest with you -- if you want to spend time chasing down why undefined behavior does this or that, then you will be mostly on your own.  Change compilers, compiler options, etc. and you may get a different behavior -- so are you willing to spend time on figuring out why a certain optimization setting changes undefined behavior?  You will quickly realize it will be like a dog chasing its own tail, and not worth the effort.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude -- on the other hand, removing m characters one at a time (as I recommended) from a string that holds n characters is going to be O(m*n). I was really making a somewhat pedantic point about clearly stating the problem to be solved.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I know all that, accessing out of bounds gives undefined behavior, but, It seems like the vector of bool capacity is greater than the vector of int capacity.

Comment: You understand that both are undefined behavior so it’s not useful to try and reason about what “seems” to be happening.

Comment: If you really want to get to the bottom of this, just look at the source code for both and see how they're implemented. Beyond that, you're not gonna get a good answer

Comment: *"seems like something special about the vector of bool"* Yes, `vector<bool>` is special in that it stores the values as single bits. That way it is likely to have a storage of 32 or 64 bits minimum. This might affect how the undefined behaviour manifests itself.

Comment: **Undefined behavior**, if you are unlucky, means that the program may appear to work correctly.  Or may crash, if you are lucky.  Or may give the expected results today, but give unexpected results tomorrow at the big presentation with your boss.  Or may email your browser history to your grandmother.  There's really no reasoning about undefined behavior because any behavior is allowed.